# How to use dataTable with getelementbyid in html and javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatable

My code

```
<div id = "showData" class="box-body"></div>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://127.0.0.1:4220/pipeline/v1/bpwi/",
      success: function (data) {
        var col = [];
        var _data = JSON.parse(data)
        for (var i = 0; i < _data.length; i++) {
          for (var key in _data[i]) {
            if (col.indexOf(key) === -1) {
              col.push(key);
            }
          }
        }

        var table = document.createElement("table");

        var tr = table.insertRow(-1);

        for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
          var th = document.createElement("th");
          th.innerHTML = col[i];
          tr.appendChild(th);
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < _data.length; i++) {
      tr = table.insertRow(-1);
      for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
        var tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
        tabCell.innerHTML = _data[i][col[j]];
      }
    }

    var divContainer = document.getElementById("showData");
    //var divContainer = $("#showData").dataTable();
    divContainer.innerHTML = "";
    divContainer.appendChild(table);
      }
    })
  })
</script>
```

This code will get me a nice table with header and data dynamically inserted but without a pagination. I would love to add a pagination and for that I already tried

```
var divContainer = document.getElementById("showData").dataTable();
```

but nothing happen. There was no table at all. I read the example for dataTable [here](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html) and it looks like I have to manually write the header first in the `div` and `table` section.

Is there a way that I can use dataTable with my current code?

Thank you for your help

Comment: just use datatable with ajax call, check [this](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html)

Comment: so I can add this ajax function I wrote above and put it in the ajax parameter in the example? How about the html part? I already tried this and it seems I have to manually write the header too. and include `table` section

Comment: just add the url and datatable will do the rest , is your case   
`$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "ajax": 'http://127.0.0.1:4220/pipeline/v1/bpwi/'
    } );
} );`
the url should return a json data

Comment: sorry, still nothing. Am I missed any parameter? It shown blank page

Comment: make sure your api return this  [form](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/data/arrays.txt)

Comment: "*How to use dataTable with getelementbyid in html and javascript?*" You cannot, gebi returns a vanilla `Element` object but DataTables is an extension of jQuey, i.e a "plugin" and is only available for a jQuery object array. Exactly the same as you cannot `document.getElementById('element').on('click', function() {` ...

Comment: did  you get a solution ?

Comment: @SoltaniNeji sorry, yes I did get the solution. I did a few adjustment to my code so it will return just like the form needed. Thank you for your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working datatables with ajax call, you just need to allow cross-origin so before running, install this [plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi) and [here](https://enable-cors.org/r) to undestand why

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').DataTable({
    "ajax": "https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/data/arrays.txt"

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<html>

<body>
  <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Extn.</th>
        <th>Start date</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Extn.</th>
        <th>Start date</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```